# GOPATH and Go Web Server: 'go run myserver.go'

Tags: go

I'm at the point where want to organize my Go web server into packages.  Currently I have everything in a few files and I simply type: **'go run server.go foo.go bar.go'**

How do I organize my files so I don't need to keep adding files to the command line.  I've investigated the GOPATH variable but it doesn't seem to work.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/myserver
```

I moved my files to the src/ subdirectory.

```
myserver/src/server.go
myserver/src/foo.go
myserver/src/bar.go
```

Shouldn't *'go run'* search $HOME/myserver/src for all go files?

I've tried these examples but they don't work.

```
go run server.go; # Doesn't work
go run src/server.go; # Doesn't work
```

By the way, all files are in 'package main'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This info is covered really well on [golang.org](https://golang.org)

Read [this](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) about how to write Go code

And [this](http://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code) about organizing go code

Tip: you can run `go run *` to run all files in a folder

Your above example should look something like this

```
$GOPATH=$HOME
```

The GOPATH should have:

```
$GOPATH
    src/
    pkg/
    bin/
```

`$GOPATH/src` is where you would store your source code for each go project

`$GOPATH/src/myserver` would contain your myserver program

cd to `$GOPATH/src/myserver` and run `go install` and you would now have your `myserver` binary  located at `$GOPATH/bin/myserver`

Add the location of your bin to your path `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` and you can run `myserver` to start your go program

Answer (score 0):

`go run` will look for a file (or wildcard) in your current working directory.

If you would like to run your programs from anywhere, either use `go build` same as you would `go run` and move the binaries where appropriate or, better yet, set your `$GOBIN` environment variable and add it your `$PATH` -- then run `go install *` in your project directory.

It's also probably a good idea to make specific directories for projects instead just dumping it all in `$GOPATH/src`